# Calculating weighted average from a list

Tags: python, weighted-average

This is one list

```
[74.0, 96.0, 72.0, 88.0, ['71', '80', '83', '77', '90', '88', '95', '71', '76', '94'], 80.0, 74.0, 98.0, 77.0]
```

74 is calculated with the weight .1, 96 with the weight .1, 72 with the weight .15, 88 with the weight .05, the average of (71,80,83,77,90,88,95,71,76,94) calculated with the weight .3, 80 calculated with the weight .08, 74 with the weight .08, 98 with .09 and lastly 77 with .05. Each score should be multiplied by appropriate weight.

Here is the function

```
def weighted_total_score(student_scores):
    return((int(student_scores[0])*.1)+(int(student_scores[1])*.1)+(int(student_scores[2])*.15)+(int(student_scores[3])*.05)+(int(student_scores[4][0])*.3)+(int(student_scores[5])*.08)+(int(student_scores[5])*.08)+(int(student_scores[5])*.09)+(int(student_scores[8])*.05))
```

The expected value should be 82.94 but i am getting 78.48

Comment: Any reason why you skipped `student_scores[5]`?

Comment: Your list has a sublist inside it. That might be the problem here. At least judging from the error message that seems to be the case.

Comment: Also, you'll get an index error after fixing the first error. You don't *have* a `student_scores[9]`.

Comment: What is your expected output? Also why do you have ints and lists mixed together? That seems like a recipe for disaster

Comment: You may want to generalize your function so it works with different weights other than the ones you have hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *slicing* the outer list:

```
student_scores[4:5][0]
```

Slicing produces a new list, in this case with one element, an the `[0]` selects *that nested list*:

```
>>> student_scores = [74.0, 96.0, 72.0, 88.0, ['71', '80', '83', '77', '90', '88', '95', '71', '76', '94'], 80.0, 74.0, 98.0, 77.0]
>>> student_scores[4:5]
[['71', '80', '83', '77', '90', '88', '95', '71', '76', '94']]
>>> student_scores[4:5][0]
['71', '80', '83', '77', '90', '88', '95', '71', '76', '94']
```

Perhaps you want to use `student_scores[4][0]` (no slicing, just the 4th element) instead? That'd produce `'71'`:

```
>>> student_scores[4][0]
'71'
```

You are also skipping `student_scores[5]`, and will get an `IndexError` for `student_scores[9]`, which doesn't exist.

You probably want to avoid typing all those direct references; specify your weights as a sequence and use `zip()` with a generator expression and `sum()` to calculate the weighted sum:

```
def weighted_total_score(student_scores):
    weights = .1, .1, .15, .05, .3, .08, .08, .09, .05                 
    return sum(int(s[0] if isinstance(s, list) else s) * w
               for s, w in zip(student_scores, weights))
```

This uses `isinstance(s, list)` to detect the one list object and extract the first value from that.

If you need the *average* of the the nested list, calculate that on the spot:

```
def average(string_scores):
    return sum(map(int, string_scores), 0.0) / len(string_scores)

def weighted_total_score(student_scores):
    weights = .1, .1, .15, .05, .3, .08, .08, .09, .05                 
    return sum(int(average(s[0]) if isinstance(s, list) else s) * w
               for s, w in zip(student_scores, weights))
```

The `average()` function here converts each string in the list to an integer, then sums those integers and divides the result by the length of the list. The `sum()` is started with a floating point 0.0 to force the total to be a float, this makes sure the division is also producing a float, this only matters on Python 2.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try this. I wasn't sure how to index the list within the list, which consisted of 10 values that needed to be averaged together.

Comment: @RachelSwamy: right, so `sum(map(int, nested_list)) / len(nested_list)`?

Comment: @RachelSwamy: also, is this Python 2 or 3? Should the average be converted to an integer too?

Comment: I just tried the code above using the zip and it is giving me 58.39 as an output. I am expecting to receive 81.94. Where did i go wrong here. By the way i am using python 3.5 @MartijnPieters

Comment: @RachelSwamy: how should I know where this goes wrong? You didn't specify anything about the expected output or how it is to be calculated. The output is correct for the weights and the assumption that all floats must be converted to `int()` before multiplying with the weight.

Comment: @RachelSwamy: it would help if you explained how the value of 81.94 is calculated. Add this to your question.

Comment: Sorry if i was not specific. The first number in the list should go with the .1, second with .1, third with .15, fourth with .05, avg. of the ten numbers with .3. etc.

Comment: @RachelSwamy: again, edit the question. Show us the sum perhaps. You haven't told us anything about what your function was supposed to do. All I could do was explain why you got the error you got, and I went an extra step by showing you an alternative way to calculate the numbers. It appears that *apart from the error* you asked the question about, your approach has other problems, but you didn't give us any details that would enable us to help you.

Comment: @RachelSwamy: the better approach is to post a **new** question to help you fix your next problem. The issues as to why you got your error is now resolved.

Comment: I have just edited my question to provide information on how the weighted score should be calculated as well as what i would like the function to do. Sorry about the confusion @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @RachelSwamy: how does that help calculate the weighted score? That's a decision tree as to what should happen with the result, not how to calculate it.